# Backup and Restore HsqlDb Embeded File (NOT DATABASE)

Tags: java, spring, backup, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

Every one talk about Backup Hsqldb outside, but what i require is to Backup the embeded files...

I'm using Spring JPA, and the application is always running, so files are in use, also since there is no DBMS, i'm wonder if there are ways to backup and restore? 
If there are, please guide me...

Otherwise, i though of copying database file, after somehow (don't know how) putting spring JPA in offline mode, and then ZIP those file, which i don't know in java, and then let user to download it, if spring allow's it... somehow (as i use stand alone spring boot, which is a single file, and it doesn't offer lot of those fancy folder, which we can point to them as website url...)

In the end in any scenario i want to send the file to client.

Sorry if i know none of this, i came from C#, and after 5 years, it's my second time using Java, which i never beem pro in it.

### UPDATE

Although i'm not sure if i can make a zip file from running database, and store it in that place... I write this code through searching, i find several method that returns current directory, but non of them point to directory i want... one of them, in debug it point to very inner location, like targer/class/x/y/z, after i package it to jar file, it may be different, another one point to C/..../temp, ... i need to get write to where my DB file is located, then pass those file to make zip file function, and tell user to download the files

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/database-manager")
public class DatabaseManager {

    private ServletContext servletContext;
    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseManager(Environment env, ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.env = env;
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get-backup", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    private FileSystemResource getBackup() throws IOException {
        //String directory = DemoApplication.class.getResource("").getPath();
        String outputLocation = servletContext.getRealPath("./");
        String dataBaseFilePath = servletContext.getRealPath(env.getProperty("application.database-file-location"));
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        String zipFile = outputLocation + "/backup-"
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)), 4, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)), 2, "0")
                + "-"
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)), 2, "0")
                + ".zip";
        ZipUtil.ToZip(new String[]{""}, zipFile);
        return new FileSystemResource(zipFile);
    }
}
```

zip function:

```
public class ZipUtil {
    public static void ToZip(String inputFiles[], String outputFile) throws IOException {
        //create byte buffer
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                /*
                 * To create a zip file, use
                 *
                 * ZipOutputStream(OutputStream out)
                 * constructor of ZipOutputStream class.
                */

        //create object of FileOutputStream
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        //create object of ZipOutputStream from FileOutputStream
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);

        for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++) {
            //create object of FileInputStream for source file
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(inputFiles[i]);

                        /*
                         * To begin writing ZipEntry in the zip file, use
                         *
                         * void putNextEntry(ZipEntry entry)
                         * method of ZipOutputStream class.
                         *
                         * This method begins writing a new Zip entry to
                         * the zip file and positions the stream to the start
                         * of the entry data.
                         */

            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(inputFiles[i]));

                        /*
                         * After creating entry in the zip file, actually
                         * write the file.
                         */
            int length;

            while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

                        /*
                         * After writing the file to ZipOutputStream, use
                         *
                         * void closeEntry() method of ZipOutputStream class to
                         * close the current entry and position the stream to
                         * write the next entry.
                         */

            zout.closeEntry();

            //close the InputStream
            fin.close();

        }


        //close the ZipOutputStream
        zout.close();
    }
}
```

### Full Answer:

I'm not sure if produce do anything, as i directly write into response inside, and return `void`.

My Response Method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get-backup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private void getBackup(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        /*//String directory = DemoApplication.class.getResource("").getPath();
        String outputLocation = servletContext.getRealPath("./");
        String dataBaseFilePath = servletContext.getRealPath(env.getProperty("application.database-file-location"));
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        String zipFile = outputLocation + "/backup-"
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)), 4, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)), 2, "0")
                + "-"
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)), 2, "0")
                + ".zip";

        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("BACKUP DATABASE TO '/tmp/backup.tar.gz' BLOCKING");
        query.executeUpdate();*/

        File zipFile = null;

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        String prefix = "DBK-"
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)), 4, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)), 2, "0")
                + "-"
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)), 2, "0")
                + StrMgr.leftPad(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)), 2, "0");
        String suffix = ".tar.gz";
        zipFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);

        zipFile.delete();

        databaseManagerRepository.Backup(zipFile.getAbsolutePath());

        response.setContentType("application/gzip");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFile.getName());

//            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
//            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            /*
             * copy from in to out
             */
        OutputStream out = null;
        FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            in = new FileInputStream(zipFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // To hold file contents
            int bytes_read; // How many bytes in buffer

            // Read a chunk of bytes into the buffer, then write them out,
            // looping until we reach the end of the file (when read() returns
            // -1). Note the combination of assignment and comparison in this
            // while loop. This is a common I/O programming idiom.
            while ((bytes_read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                // Read until EOF
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read); // write
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
        // Always close the streams, even if exceptions were thrown
        finally {
            if (in != null)
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    ;
                }
            if (out != null)
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    ;
                }
        }

        zipFile.delete();
    }
```

My Backup Native SQL Action Executor

```
@Repository
public class DatabaseManagerRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /*The query force us to use transaction, and since the DB is online and we use spring, it also force us to use spring transaction*/
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    public void Backup(String outputDir) {
            //NOT BLOCKING -> For large database, backup is performed while the database perform other operations
            //AS FILES -> We only define directory not the file itself
            Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("BACKUP DATABASE TO '" + outputDir + "' BLOCKING"/*" AS FILES"*/);
            q.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup is the same with an HSQLDB Server or embedded database. You execute the SQL statement:

```
BACKUP DATABASE TO <directory name> BLOCKING AS FILES
```

The directory name is a path to the target directory to store the backup files. For example `BACKUP DATABASE TO 'C://db_backups/' BLOCKING AS FILES`

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_online_backup

The AS FILES backup database creates a set of files which you can zip.

Comment: it's still incomplete, i need to send it to client, i also edit my  Question, as i when i wrote it, i only merge second section with requirment to send to client, also i share my exprience. also i need to know, how to call this stetment when i use JPA interface per entity...

Comment: You can do what you like with the backup file (its a gzip file by default). If your question is how to send a gzip file to the client with Spring Boot, you can ask it as a separate question to get good answers.

Comment: I updated the answer to produce the files you need to zip. Someone else can answer the second part of your question. You should not just zip the files of a running database. Use the BACKUP statement.

Comment: You are asking some different questions. I don't know the answer to the parts I did not answer. As I said, ask a new question for each part and someone else will answer.

Comment: You know naything about: `org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [BACKUP DATABASE TO C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\DBK-2239804649052983060-20161123-301458.tar.gz BLOCKING AS FILES]
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterParser.parse(ParameterParser.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParamLocationRecognizer.parseLocations(ParamLocationRecognizer.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at` ...

Comment: You need single quote characters around the path. I am updating my answer.

Comment: it says: `The archive is either in unknown format or damaged` is send it with this header... `response.setContentType("application/zip");` and this extension: `.tar.gz`

Comment: This is called the MIME type. It is usually setContentType("application/gzip") for the "gz" extension. Note gzip is different from zip.

Comment: thanks... BTW in case off need, can you tell me how to restore database? it will be great if i could perform it online like last action, user send file to controller, and i run a command like you shown me before, otherwise if there is no restore action, tell me any other possible way, and should destroyed database file exists that i restore it? or i can delete them and restore it? -------- i still get same error when i even use 'application/gzip'

Comment: Read the HSQLDB Guide at the URL I gave.

Comment: i just noticed that the file is empty, and after sometime i found out that after `entityManager.createNativeQuery("BACKUP DATABASE TO '" + outputDir + "' BLOCKING AS FILES");` i need to pass it to a query and call `q.executeUpdate();` once i done it, it generate error `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query` i do not see any other execute method that does not come with update in name :|

Comment: I also switched to `Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:./PersonnelDb", "sa", "pass"); Statement st = conn.createStatement();
 st.execute("BACKUP DATABASE TO \"" + outputDir + "\" BLOCKING AS FILES");` But it didn't worked either and generated errors :|

Comment: The TransactionRequiredExcpetion means you need to start a transaction before the execute. The error in the last message is because you are using double quotes instead of single quotes around the `outputDir`

Comment: i used single quote at first, it said \ is invalid and / is valid, then i change to that, it said '' is invalid, then i change to double quote , and change to backslash again and ... i try that once i got home

Comment: i begin transaction and it said use spring, then i used `@Transactional`, so it generate `2016-12-24 17:24:27.454 ERROR 280 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unsupported suffix in file name ''.  (Supported suffixes:  /) in statement [BACKUP DATABASE TO 'C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\DBK-1084903049413007374-20161124-502418.tar.gz' BLOCKING AS FILES]` this time :| wont it work on windows?

Comment: Just write it as I suggested. When you give it a file name, you don't use AS FILES. When you don't use a file name, you should give the path to an empty directory, not the Temp directory itself, and no file name.

Comment: thank you, there is script and properties file on backup :) sorry to take out so much time...